# Windows 10 C: drive capacity smaller then C: partition size

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I went through a whole process up to this point. I tried restoring from an image backup, but windows wouldn't boot from it. I booted into ubuntu from a usb stick and mucked about with the partitioning, eventually expanding c: to fill the rest of the free space. Predictably after that windows still wouldn't boot so I decided to just reinstall windows fresh since I could manually copy files from the backup image anyways. I spent a while setting my fresh windows install up till I noticed my c drive was much smaller then expected.

In disk management the total capacity of c: is reported as 111.19GB, but the partition size of c: is 930.88GB. Screenshot showing this in disk management:

[image]

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Though Windows does not report it, the _filesystem_ has a fixed size. After extending the partition itself, the filesystem also needs to be extended, as you found out. // I recommend altering Windows partitions only using Disk Management or `diskpart` as much as possible. It is the safest way to deal with NTFS partitions.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for the information! That's a good explanation and advice. That knowledge will definitely come in handy in the future. I didn't know that NTFS was different in any way and modifying it outside of diskpart could cause issues

Comment: NTFS isn’t _different_. It’s just that NTFS is a proprietary filesystem that is developed by Microsoft, so using Microsoft tools is the safe choice.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution in the following thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hard-disk-capacity-shows-wrong-size/31c7229e-aadc-4716-a867-ee5beaf0549e

Copy and pasted solution:

> 1. Close any open applications
> 2. Click your Start Button, then just type `cmd`
> 3. On the resulting list, right click Command Prompt and choose 'Run as Administrator'
> 4. Run this command and press Enter:
>
>    ```
>    diskpart
>    ```
> 5. Run this command and press Enter:
>
>    ```
>    list volume
>    ```
> 6. Run this command and press Enter (replace # with the volume number of that C drive partition)
>
>    ```
>    select volume #
>    ```
> 7. Run this command and press Enter:
>
>    ```
>    extend filesystem
>    ```
>
> When that command completes, close Command Prompt and re-start (not shut down) your PC, then check the reported size of that partition.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're looking at the wrong drive. Your C: partition is on Disk 3, which has a total of 931GB, and you're looking at Disk 2, which has 111.19GB.

Comment: No; You are looking at the wrong drive. DISK 3 has three partition(s). There is most definitely something wrong about that disk's partition table.

Comment: The partition is displayed as 930.88 GB on the diagram, but the filesystem is listed as 111.19 GB at the top.