File Explorer shows disk volume smaller than it is supposed to be
I cloned a 500GB SSD to 2TB SSD with Clonezilla 3.1.2 using instructions as listed here https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone. I tried both options -k0 and -k1. This screenshot shows the SSD with -k1 option.

The partition shows up correct. But the C volume still shows up with the size of old SSD. How can I fix that?

does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/1751451/windows-10-c-drive-capacity-smaller-then-c-partition-size

Yes this is the solution. Thanks a lot.
